# Is there any Sapling contract on mainnet?

Tags: smart-contracts, privacy

Is there on mainnet any deployed Sapling contract that anyone really uses (through tezos-client, as I believe it's the only supported way to do it now)?

Answer (score 0):

There is one that can be used, it needs more activity.
https://tzstats.com/KT1KzAPQdpziH3bxxJXQNmNQA46oo8tnDQfj